# Verify value of column in table is not equal to the sum of values of two columns in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, with the following schema;

#### Table A

- id
- b_id
- amount

#### Table B

- id
- amount

#### Table C

- id
- a_id
- fee_amount

Tables A and B are related directly, however, table C has `a_id` that may be NULL.

I am trying to put together an SQL query to return the rows whose value of A.amount != B.amount + C.amount.
So far I have this;

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.a_id = a.id 
WHERE a.amount > 5000 AND a.amount != (b.amount + c.fee_amount)
```

With a simple dataset like this;

#### Table A

```
| id | b_id | amount |
|----|------|--------|
| 1  | 1    | 50000  |
```

#### Table B

```
| id | amount |
|----|--------|
| 1  | 5000   |
```

#### Table C

```
| id | a_id | fee_amount |
|----|------|------------|
| 1  | 1    | 7000       |
```

And the query returns zero results. I'm pretty I've missed something, just not sure what it is.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem? E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 can be used.

Comment: *table C has a_id that may be NULL.* If `a_id` IS NULL then this row is not related to any row in `a`. Maybe you mean that there may not exist any row in `c` which relates to a row in `a`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *Tables A and B are related directly* But this does not guarantee that each row in `a` has related row(s) in `b`.

Comment: Provide **COMPLETE** CREATE TABLE scripts for all tables, including primary/unique indices and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to handle the NULLs by treating them as 0 - eg:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.a_id = a.id 
WHERE a.amount > 5000 AND a.amount != (IFNULL(b.amount, 0) + IFNULL(c.fee_amount,0))
```

Comment: This query does not take into account that there can be more than one row in `b` related to a row in `a`.

Comment: @ Akina - The question only specified that c could be NULL, so the relationship to b was the same as the original query. You're right though, for completeness I have added IFNULL to b as well.

Comment: I agree that the question gives the facts only partially.

Answer (score 0):

First, if only `C` can have the `NULL` value, then you are better off using the `LEFT JOIN` only for that table:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON b.id = a.b_id LEFT JOIN
     c
     ON c.a_id = a.id 
WHERE a.amount > 5000 AND
      a.amount <> (b.amount + COALESCE(c.fee_amount, 0)) ;
```

However, normally you have secondary tables like this because the tables can have *multiple* rows per `a_id`.  If that is the case, you need some sort of aggregation.